# session from one app affecting different app on local host

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app that uses sessions and which I was using in Chrome on localhost. After I shut it down, I started up another app in Chrome that doesn't use sessions and got a sessions error referring to a class that doesn't exist in the new sessionless app.

```
ActionDispatch::Session::SessionRestoreError (Session contains objects whose class definition isn't available.
Remember to require the classes for all objects kept in the session.
(Original exception: uninitialized constant Question [NameError])
):
```

When I try the new 'sessionless' app in another browser (that I didn't use before), it works fine even while it continues not to work in Chrome, so i'm guessing that the sessions from the first app are hanging around in chrome and interferring with the second.  I cleared the cache but it's still not working (so I probably have to clear it again 1000 more times in Chrome), however, I also found this method

```
reset_session
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000668

but when I put it in Application controller (hoping it would clear all sessions throughout the app), it says undefined local variable or method.

Two questions

1) is the behavior expected, namely that the sessions from the first app affect the functioning of the second app?

2) how should I be using reset_session to avoid this problem, or is there another way to?

update
the app worked in Chrome after clearing the cache, but I'd still like to know how to use reset_session if possible

Answer (score 0):

A rails best practice is to use Ruby Version Manager. Re-installing ruby with RVM will be less time consuming than debugging problems like these.

https://rvm.io/

Comment: I uninstalled rvm to use rbenv. Didn't realize that rvm took care of sessions in this way.

Comment: To be honest, it may not. I wouldn't switch again until you compare the differences of both. You will likely find your answer to your main question while doing that.